# How to convert a number to specific digit number in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have an array of numbers like this:

```
numbers = [9,20,62,500,2,10]
```

I want all array elements to match the number of digits found in the largest number. In this case, the largest element is `500`. So expected output is,

```
[009,020,062,500,002,010]
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this on your own?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume **3 digits** is now a string. You could use (if no restrictions on browser compability), [padStart](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart):

```js
const appendThreeDigits = (source = []) => source.map((number) => number.toString().padStart(3, '0'));
const numbers = [9,20,62,500,2,10];


console.log(appendThreeDigits(numbers));
```

Comment: @DelegentTech generally, not a good practice to update a question after there are answers. However, since it was a quick fix, I also updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Math.max() to get the highest number, convert it to a string to measure the length and use Intl to set the minimum Integer digits:

```js
    let numbers = [5,10,300,7,8]
    const maxLength = Math.max(...numbers).toString().length
    const formattedNumbers = numbers.map(number=> new Intl.NumberFormat('en', { minimumIntegerDigits:maxLength }).format(number));
    console.log(formattedNumbers)
```

Reference:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat/NumberFormat